# Can't select machine group from Build tasks dropdown in TFS 2015.2

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to use the Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment Build vNext task in TFS 2015.2. I added a machine group in the Test tab, but when trying to select the machine group in the dropdown in the build task for the Test Agent Deployment, the UI thought that there were no groups! (clicked on the dropdown, wouldn't have anything show up)

We refreshed the page and no difference. And this issue seems to appear for all of the build tasks. We tried a Windows File Copy task and typed in the Machine Groups manually and the task succeeded, so TFS does recognize the groups. I'm experiencing the issue as a TFS Admin. This has happened to more than one environment of an install for us.

Has anyone else seen this issue with TFS 2015.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not see this issue on my side. Try another supported browser to see whether you would have the same issue.

Supported browsers:

- Internet Explorer, versions 9, 10, 11, and 12
- Mozilla Firefox, latest version (27)
- Google Chrome, latest version (32)
- Safari (supported on Macs only), version 7

Comment: Nope, looks like it works on Chrome/IE on different machines. :(

Comment: Neither Chrome nor IE works on your computer, but works on other machines? Seems like the issue is not from TFS side, you may try to reset the setting of your browser to see whether it woks or not.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, doesn't work in any browser on my machine or other machines.

Comment: You mentioned this issue seems to appear for all of the build tasks, does it mean all drop-down list can't be shown on your TFS web access? For example, can you see the drop-down list of "Visual Studio Version" in "Visual Studio Build" task?

Comment: Yeah, the dropdowns were accessible for others. To resolve this as a workaround, I just uploaded the OOB task from VSTS and that got rid of the dropdown. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, I posted a request on the microsoft forums.

The cause is a call to the distributed task coordinator:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Team Foundation Server" Guid="{80761876-6844-47D5-8106-F8ED2AA8687B}" /> 
  <EventID>0</EventID> 
  <Version>3</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>1</Task> 
  <Opcode>10</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000001</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-12T09:09:21.717163200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>59667</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{6AD40FD3-10BA-4A7E-B6D9-F6926072DAB4}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="3376" ThreadID="6484" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Team Foundation Server/Debug</Channel> 
  <Computer>TKBSV021.TKB.local</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-2105344776-4230907741-261866850-3716" /> 
  </System>
- <UserData>
- <Info TraceId="{00000001-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2010/Framework">
  <Tracepoint>103200</Tracepoint> 
  <ServiceHost>{87670F79-6386-4363-9960-73B634419263}</ServiceHost> 
  <ContextId>10082</ContextId> 
  <ProcessName>w3wp</ProcessName> 
  <Username>TKB\tmpadmin</Username> 
  <VSID>{9E83242F-9944-4CBD-AF10-EF2D449A03B1}</VSID> 
  <Service>Web-Api</Service> 
  <Method>TaskDefinitionWebApiProxy.QueryEndpoint</Method> 
  <Area>DistributedTask</Area> 
  <Layer>TaskDefinitionWebApiProxy</Layer> 
  <UserAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko</UserAgent> 
  <Uri>/tfs/Default/_apis/distributedtask/endpoint</Uri> 
  <Path /> 
  <UniqueIdentifier>{A9646429-41CB-4137-A39A-D4E29EDDC389}</UniqueIdentifier> 
  <UserDefined /> 
  <ExceptionType>Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.ServiceEndpointQueryFailedException</ExceptionType> 
  <Message>Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.ServiceEndpointQueryFailedException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Server.WebApiProxy.HttpRequestProxy.ExecuteRequest(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, IList`1 sourceDefinitions, DataSource dataSource) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Server.Controllers.TaskDefinitionWebApiProxyController.QueryEndpoint(TaskDefinitionEndpoint endpoint) at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()</Message> 
  </Info>
  </UserData>
  </Event>
```

Fiddler reports it is the following request is failing :

POST `http://localhost:8080/tfs/Default/_apis/distributedtask/endpoint HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Interesting, that's a good find. Do you have the link for where you posted in the MS forum?

Comment: What I ended up just doing was uploading the VSTS task version that removed the dropdown completely (with the Machines text field) using tfx-cli and it seemed to fix it, but that's a strange workaround when it seems like this issue is sporadic.

Comment: @Sashi I have met the same problem, how did you resolve it?