# TFS 2015 - Test machine group dropdown empty and getting 401 error on api call

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines

This is related to question [#36574843](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574843/tfs-2015-machine-groups-cannot-be-selected-in-build-deployment-definition-vnext), where when we create a build definition and add the "Visual Studio test Agent Deployment" step, the Machine group list is empty. Note that prior to installing TFS 2015 Update 2.1, this was working. However now when I inspect the network requests for that dropdown, I can see the request fails with the following:

```
Status: 400 Bad request

Request Url: http://[our tfs server url]/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/distributedtask/endpoint

Response body:{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.ServiceEndpointQueryFailedException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","typeKey":"ServiceEndpointQueryFailedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

We have a machine group setup, and prior to installing update 2.1, could select the machine group with no issues. However, now it is failing, and we need to find out why....

Comment: The same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416981/cant-select-machine-group-from-build-tasks-dropdown-in-tfs-2015-2/36574414

Comment: After turning on failed request tracing on the TFS site, I've also noticed that other requests are now failing with 401 errors too. E.g. http://...//tfs/_apis/distributedtask/pools/1/messages?sessionId=2962c27c-90e6-475b-ac93-e0c7ce4f8bd1

I've tried connecting via tfx-cli as per the referenced post, after enabling basic auth, and I still get a 401 after that

Comment: Can you check if you still have the permission to access to the agent pool after upgrade? And can you also try to remove the old build agent and then download the build agent from web portal and reconfigure a totally new one to see if it can works?

Comment: I've tried reinstalling the build agent. It is able to perform builds and therefore communicate with TFS. I am also able to access the agent pool after the upgrade. However, when I (and my account is a TFS admin) use the web portal release management section, I still get the error as described, and the dropdown is empty.

Comment: Can you try the work around in this question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/842819e2-a7e7-4446-849d-f44ae71906c2/machine-groups-not-available-when-creating-new-build-definition?forum=tfsbuild?

Comment: Unbelievable - changing the notification url and doing the IIS reset actually worked! Note that just doing each one on its own wasn't enough; I had to do both. I also tried adding a different hostname binding on port 80, but the only thing that made the dropdown populate was changing the notification url and doing the IIS reset.

This would surely be something to look at for update 3?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to this was as per my most recent comment, and the [referenced issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/842819e2-a7e7-4446-849d-f44ae71906c2/machine-groups-not-available-when-creating-new-build-definition?forum=tfsbuild) from Eddie - MSFT.

I had to:

- change the TFS notification url on the TFS server in the admin console so it didn't use the fqdn (in my case from http://myservername.domain.company.com:8080/tfs to http://myservername:8080/tfs since it's all on the same domain)
- do an IIS reset

Since then the dropdowns have been fully populated and the issue has not recurred. Note that if I changed the notification url back to the fqdn, the dropdowns immediately broke again :-(